# malloc() for an array of strings, not working as hoping

Tags: c, arrays, string, malloc, buffer

I am trying to make a function that takes a string and a pointer to an array of strings and `malloc()` the array of char arrays and copies each individual word of the string. This is what I have so far, I think I'm close, I'm just struggling with using `malloc()` on an array of arrays.

```
int string_parser(char *inp, char **array_of_words_p[])
{
    int CurrentChar = 0;                //Variable Initialization
    char *buffer;                       //Variable Initialization

    /* Allocate memory and check for errors allocating memory */
    //Allocate memory to buffer the size of the input string
    buffer = (char*)malloc(strlen(inp));    
    if (buffer == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error allocating memory..\n");
        return -1;
    }

    /* Move input string into buffer before processing */
    for (CurrentChar = 0; CurrentChar < strlen(inp) + 1; CurrentChar++)
    {   //For every character in input
        if (inp != NULL)                                                    
        {
            //Move input character into buffer
            buffer[CurrentChar] = inp[CurrentChar];     
        }
    }

    /* Convert string into array of words */
    char ** stringbuffer = NULL;        

    //Convert string to array of words
    char *  CurrentWord = strtok_s(buffer, " ", *array_of_words_p);     

    //Variable Initialization
    int numspaces = 0;

    while (CurrentWord)                                                 
    {
        //Allocate memory for size of string
        stringbuffer = (char**)realloc(stringbuffer, sizeof(char**) * ++numspaces); 
        if (stringbuffer == NULL)                                       
        {
            return -1;
        }
        stringbuffer[numspaces - 1] = CurrentWord;

        //Reset Current word to null        
        CurrentWord = strtok_s(NULL, " ", *array_of_words_p);       
    }

    //Reallocate memory to include terminating character
    stringbuffer = (char**)realloc(stringbuffer, sizeof(char**) * (numspaces + 1)); 
    stringbuffer[numspaces] = 0;                                        

    /* Write processed data into returned argument */
    *array_of_words_p = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char**) * (numspaces + 2));           
    memcpy(*array_of_words_p, stringbuffer, (sizeof(char*) * (numspaces + 2))); 

    free(stringbuffer);                                             
    return numspaces;                                                   
}
```

Comment: Please add a C/C++ tag

Comment: What is the question / problem?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>     //Allocate memory to buffer the size of the input string
>     buffer = (char*)malloc(strlen(inp));
> ```

The *size of the input string* includes the terminating `\0`, so you need:

```
    buffer = malloc(strlen(inp)+1);
```

> ```
>     //Convert string to array of words
>     char *  CurrentWord = strtok_s(buffer, " ", *array_of_words_p);
> ```

It's unwise to abuse the `*array_of_words_p` for the context save variable, as this requires it to be initialized appropriately. Better:

```
    char *context, *CurrentWord = strtok_s(buffer, " ", &context);
    …
        CurrentWord = strtok_s(NULL, " ", &context);
```

> ```
>         //Allocate memory for size of string
>         stringbuffer = (char**)realloc(stringbuffer, sizeof(char**) * ++numspaces);
> ```

It likely doesn't hurt (owing to equal pointer sizes), but `sizeof(char**)` is strictly speaking wrong, since the elements of the *array of strings* are of type `char *`. Correct:

```
        stringbuffer = realloc(stringbuffer, sizeof (char *) * ++numspaces);
    …
    stringbuffer = realloc(stringbuffer, sizeof (char *) * (numspaces + 1));
```

> ```
>     /* Write processed data into returned argument */
>     *array_of_words_p = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char**) * (numspaces + 2));           
>     memcpy(*array_of_words_p, stringbuffer, (sizeof(char*) * (numspaces + 2))); 
>
>     free(stringbuffer);
> ```

You can spare this unnecessary copying and by the way avoid accessing the unallocated memory `stringbuffer[numspaces+1]` by replacing the above with just:

```
    *array_of_words_p = stringbuffer;
```

Apart from that all, your function works and can be called like:

```
    char **array_of_words;
    int n = string_parser("this here is an example string", &array_of_words);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) puts(array_of_words[i]);
```